# How to effciently solve a radical equation of the form $0=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\sqrt{|b_j-x|}$?

Tags: roots

Given a radical equation of the form
$$0=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\sqrt{|b_j-x|}$$
where $b_j>0$ and the sign of $a_j\in\mathbb R$ matches that of $b_j-x$, is there any more efficient (analytical?) solution for $x$ than iteratively putting one square root to the other side, squaring twice (to get rid of the absolute value), isolating another root and repeating, effectively yielding a polynomial of an order that increases with $n$? Is there some upper limit on $n$ for which an analytical solution exists?

**edit** The simplification I meant to do was allowing $a_j^2\in\mathbb R$ (i.e. $a_j$ may be purely imaginary as well) such that $a_j^2(b_j-x)\ge0$, reducing the original equation to
$$0=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\sqrt{b_j-x}$$
so squaring is required only once.

Comment: The sum of positive numbers is zero, so each term has to be zero. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Sorry, I screwed up with a "simplification". The $a_j$'s belong in front of the square roots...